# Check if tiles are loading

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am using OL-layerswitcher (https://github.com/walkermatt/ol-layerswitcher) to produce a sidebar with my layers and add them to the map when clicking. Unfortunately, this might take some time depending on the internet connection, etc. and thus I would like to add an icon showing that something is happening while it is loading.

I managed to create a div in the middle of my screen showing the icon I want to show but I am not able to check if something is still loading or not.
Since I am using the layerswitcher, my layers are not clearly defined as variables (like in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/tile-load-events.html), thus I can not use the example.

If anyone can help me, thank you.

EDIT: I am trying to get this running with a single layer.Tile now. I thought if i do it like this and add the source-Layer to my map I should get a console-output "Loading" and then "Done", but I do not get an output.

```
var source = new ol.layer.Tile({
                    title: "Baden-Württemberg",
                    zIndex: 2,
                    visible: false,
                    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                        url: "https://forestwatch.lup-umwelt.de/app/ows/index.php/geoserver/forestwatch/wms?",
                            params: {
                                'LAYERS': "forestwatch:baden_wuertemberg_maske"
                            }
                        
                    })
                })
                
var IMG = document.getElementById("loading");

source.on('tileloadstart', function () {
   console.log("Loading");
    });

source.on('tileloadend', function () {
   console.log("Done");
});
```

PS: I do not really care if I have to use jquery, if there is a solution using it just tell me.

Edit: @Mike made this work using source.getSource().on(   ), but right now my map is jumping.

```
#loading {
position: relative;
display: none;
font-size: 40px;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
z-index: 10000;
/*    width: 30px;
height: 30px;*/
background-color: transparent;
color: black;
}
```

This is the css for the div. EDIT: position: fixed made it work since it is always in the same position now.

Comment: Do you have a Live example ? or much more of your code

Comment: @JB_DELR I added some code of a single-Layer example. My html is basically a map and with a div (id = "loading") as an overlay (Even though I would be happy to get this stuff to even give a console log)

Comment: Your variable `source` is a layer.  To listen to events on its source you will need `source.getSource().on(...)`

Comment: Thank you @Mike! It works now! Would you post it as an answer so I can accept it? Edit: I got another question: If I use this I get the map "jumping" up and down during loading, any idea why?

Comment: If it is jumping when you hide and show a div it is probably a css issue.

Comment: I will add my css to the question (better readability than in comments I guess) EDIT: Found a solution for it, I had to change to position: fixed and it is working now!